# Get Nested Value from Request.form

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to extract some values from data I received using "POST" method in c# webforms, sample data is:

```
{  
   "ProductStockDetailsID":8015425,
   "LocationID":24213,
   "ProductID":19284305,
   "MinStock":null,
   "MaxStock":null,
   "OnOrder":0,
   "Alerts":false,
   "ProductStocks":[  
    {  
     "StockID":11839663,
     "CurrentStock":68,
     "CurrentVolume":0,
     "CreatedDate":"2019-06-30T09:58:38.4",
     "DeletedDate":null,
     "CostPrice":0.00000,
     "ProductStockDetailsID":8015425
    }
   ]
}
```

I use `Request.Form["ProductID"]` to extract the `ProductID` successfully, But I'm not able to extract the `CurrentStock` values because it looks to be nested from `ProductStocks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define the class for request and then just parse the request. TO do this you need to override ProcessRequest method like

```html
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        string json;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestData>(json);

        base.ProcessRequest(context);

        ProcessRequest(data);
    }
    
 private void ProcessRequest(RequestData data)
 {
 // ... your code 
 }
```

And the class to parse is:

```html
public class RequestData
{
    public int ProductStockDetailsID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public object MinStock { get; set; }
    public object MaxStock { get; set; }
    public int OnOrder { get; set; }
    public bool Alerts { get; set; }
    public Productstock[] ProductStocks { get; set; }
}

public class Productstock
{
    public int StockID { get; set; }
    public int CurrentStock { get; set; }
    public int CurrentVolume { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public object DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public float CostPrice { get; set; }
    public int ProductStockDetailsID { get; set; }
}
```

Now just use `data.ProductStocks`

Comment: Thank you @SouXin, is there any other way without overriding?

Comment: You can try to parse request to anonymous function but this is nightmare. Just curious what is wrong with overriding.

Comment: Thank you @SouXin, it is because I was looking for a simple way just to use Currentstock only, for example (string CurrentStock = Request.Form["ProductStocks[0]CurrentStock"];)